# Is there a way to uninstall BigCommerce app for app owner?

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm setting up two BC applications and here's a scenario when I need to remove one of them from users store. Is there a way for app owner to initiate uninstall process?
In docs I saw only user-initiated uninstall

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a method for an app to be "force uninstalled" from the app creator's end apart from invalidating the token by essentially deleting the app. We can definitely take that as a feature request, though. If you're able to share any additional details about your scenario for needing to uninstall an app from your end, that would be helpful context for our team.

Comment: Hello Karen.
Generally we'll have two applications: one with limited functionality, second will repeat that functionality and some additional.
Why I want to implement those limits with two applications: second will require bigger set of scopes and I don't want to ask user for scopes he doesn't need.
So at the point user has first (limited) application installed and installs second app I'm going to uninstall limited one for user to keep it clean and make user interact only with extended application.